# Relationships between fractional Sobolev space, Bessel spacse and Hajłasz–Sobolev space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-pde, parabolic-pde

It is known that for $\alpha\in(0,1)$ and $p>1$,

the fractional Sobolev space $W^{\alpha,p}(R^n)$ is defined by
$$
W^{\alpha,p}(R^n):=\{f\in L^p(R^n):\int_{R^n}\int_{R^n}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|^p}{|x-y|^{n+\alpha p}}dx dy<\infty\},
$$
and the Bessel space $H^{\alpha,p}(R^n)$ is defined by
$$
H^{\alpha,p}(R^n):=\{f\in L^p(R^n):\Delta^{\alpha/2}f\in L^p(R^n)\}.
$$
There is also another kind of space known as Hajłasz–Sobolev space which is defined by
$$
M^{\alpha,p}(R^n):=\{f\in L^p(R^n):|f(x)-f(y)|\leq|x-y|^\alpha[g(x)+g(y)],a.e. x,y\in R^n, where\,\, g\in L^p(R^n)\,\, is\,\, nonnegative\}.
$$

Is there any relationship between $M^{\alpha,p}$ with $H^{\alpha,p}$ or $W^{\alpha,p}$?

Many thanks for the answer!

Comment: Try this: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/03/11/a-type-diagram-for-function-spaces/

Comment: Check the papers of Dachun Yang.